ImproperlyConfigured: TaggableManager is not supported by modeltranslation
settings.py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'tcore',
'ckeditor',
'modeltranslation',
'taggit',
]
models.py
from taggit.managers import TaggableManager
tags = TaggableManager()
views.py
class BaseView(object):def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
context['Categories'] = Category.objects.all()
context['PBlogs'] = Blog.objects.order_by('-views')[:5]
context['most_common_tags']=Tag.objects.annotate(num_times=Count('taggit_taggeditem_items')).ord
er_by('-num_times')[:5]
return context
Error Received:
File "C:\Users\python\Project\env\lib\site-packages\modeltranslation\fields.py", line 81, in create_translation_field
raise ImproperlyConfigured("%s is not supported by modeltranslation." % cls_name)

django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: TaggableManager is not supported by modeltranslation.
fields.py
if empty_value not in ("", "both", None, NONE):
raise ImproperlyConfigured("%s is not a valid empty_value." % empty_value)
field = cast(fields.Field, model._meta.get_field(field_name))
cls_name = field.class.name
if not (isinstance(field, SUPPORTED_FIELDS) or cls_name in mt_settings.CUSTOM_FIELDS):
raise ImproperlyConfigured("%s is not supported by modeltranslation." % cls_name)
translation_class = field_factory(field.class)
return translation_class(translated_field=field, language=lang, empty_value=empty_value)

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
